Subsetting multiple values in a single variable into two groups
I want to do regression analyses on particular groups of values of a single variable which need sub setting eg:
sdata = subset(data, variable X =="1" | variable X == "5") which works fine
sdata1 = subset(data, variable X == "1,2,3" | variable X == "4, 5") doesn't work
It doesn't like the "," in the second example.  I specifically want to be able to compare the first group to the second and not a series eg
sdata3 = subset(data, variable X =="1" | variable X == "2" | variable X == "3") 


subset(data, variable_X %in% c("1","2","3") | variable_X %in% c("4", "5"))?

If you're using the same Variable_X both times, you could just do variable_X %in% c("1","2","3","4","5")
